# Xpath is not working,I am using appium to locate an xpath

Tags: selenium, xpath, appium

xpath suggested by app itself is not working

```
xpath : //[@accessibilityLabel=‘iconUncheck’ and (./preceding-sibling:: ./following-sibling::)[@id=‘Prod Test’]]
```

Please help me in building the xpath.
Element which I want to click
[image]

properties of thee element.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try the bellow `xpath`:

```
//*[@class='UIAImage' and ./following-sibling::*[@class='UIAView' and contains(text(),'Bone Marrow')]]
```

Or

```
//*[@class='UIAImage' and ./following-sibling::*[contains(text(),'Bone Marrow')]]
```